# MEF multiple instances same constructor

Tags: c#, mef

Is there a way for MEF to create multiple instances of the same class with different constructor arguments?

E.G.

```
class MefTest
{
    [Test]
    public void Test()
    {
        var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog(new TypeCatalog(typeof(MyExportType)));

        var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

        compositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue("Ctor1", "Contructor argument 1");
        compositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue("Ctor2", "Contructor argument 2");

        var exportedValues = compositionContainer.GetExportedValues<MyExportType>();

        Assert.AreEqual(2, exportedValues.Count());
    }
}

[Export]
class MyExportType
{
    internal string Name { get; set; }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    internal MyExportType([Import("Ctor1")][Import("Ctor2")]string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

The example will complain about the multiple ImportAttribute.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that.

As you can read in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.composition.importingconstructorattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), the .ctor decorated with the `[ImportingConstructor]` attribute will use its parameters as imports. Each import must be satisfied according to default policies or attributes you optionally provide (e.g. `[ImportMany]` or `[Import(AllowDefault=true)]`).

So you cannot use the .ctor arguments for your needs, they are "reserved" for imports.